# react-native : use url.parse

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I was using `url.parse` from node in react-native `0.54.0` (Expo SDK 26)

```
const url = require("url");

const { hostname, pathname } = url.parse(props.currentMessage.image);
var extension = pathname.substr(pathname.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

// determine file URL
const fileURL = `https://${hostname}${pathname}`;
```

When updating to SDK 27, and so moving to RN `0.55.2`, i faced this issue

> You attempted attempted to import the Node standard library module "url" from "src/modules/xxx/xxx.js". It failed because React Native does not include the Node standard library. Read more at https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq.html#can-i-use-nodejs-packages-with-expo

### Few questions :

Is it related to my implementation ?

It seems like it is related to React-native, is this going to get solve by itself when i will update to SDK 28, 29, 30 ?

Is there any alternative that would allow me to do the same without adding any other dependencies ?

(ps: No need to suggest dependencies for this simple use-case such as 'url' or 'whatwg-url', i won't do that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current bundler implementation has banned all node standard library references. Even if it does not include native implementations (in c++).

`url` does not use native implementations, although, you have to install it as a package in order to make React Natives bundler to understand it as a dependency.

Answering Your questions:

- Is it related to my implementation?

Yes, do not import from node directly

- [...] is this going to get solved by itself when I will update[...]?

Nope, this is related to how React Native packages your javascript and put  into your `.apk` ou `.ipa` file. I don't think it will be changed for a while.

- Is there any alternative that would allow me to do the same without adding any other dependencies?

Yes, copy and paste the [source code](https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-url/blob/master/url.js) or implement it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable explanation. Do you have a link to a documentation or a blog annoucement about the "banned all node standard library references" thing ?
I moved from 0.54 to 0.55 and everything was going well before that.
 I'll let this question open for other answers for a bit longer in order to encourage other alternative suggestions ;)

Comment: I later found this link
https://docs.expo.io/versions/v27.0.0/introduction/faq#can-i-use-nodejs-packages-with-expo

So i ended up adding `https://www.npmjs.com/package/url` to my package.json and it works now. Thanks for the help :)